# CCK field prefixes?

Tags: drupal, cck

How would I add a prefix to a text field? For example, I have a field called "website" which is currently displayed like this:

```
website: ____________
```

Where **_ is the input field. With the module "field markup" i can add prefix and suffixes but they apppear AFTER the _** or before the website part. I need to end up with:

```
website: http:// ____________
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter` to modify a textfield's [`#field_prefix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/5#field_prefix) (as opposed to `#prefix`). You could also use the CCK Link module to provide a proper URL field, that'll add http:// as necessary and validate the URL's format.

Comment: I do use CCK link, but it does not add http to the front? Maybe I should upgrade the version I am using.

Comment: I dont think LINK CCk offers this. Going to try your other suggestion now.

Comment: The Link CCK field doesn't put http:// in front, but it does make sure the user entered a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it using the '#after-build' mechanism so that CCK has already constructed the form elements.

```
<?php
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'your_module_form_after_build_function';
}

function your_module_form_after_build_function($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['field_your_field_name'][0]['value']['#field_prefix'] = t('Example Prefix');
  $form['field_your_field_name'][0]['value']['#field_suffix'] = t('Example Suffix');
}
?>
```

You may also need to adjust the CSS so that the text field doesn't clear (if you want your prefix or suffix to appear on the same line as the textfield).

See #after-build in the forms api reference:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#after_build

Comment: Ooops. My answer is specifically for adding prefixes or suffixes to CCK fields, not regular text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Also the [Form Builder](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) module allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Simple Field Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter) module, see the below screenshot

> [image]

Which allows site administrators to easily control the display of
field values with following features

> - Prepend the field value with specified text/HTML
> - Append the field value with specified text/HTML
> - Reverse the Field Value
> - Trim the Field Value
> - Convert the field value to lowercase letters
> - Convert the field value to uppercase letters
> - Convert the first character of the field value to uppercase
> - Convert the first character of each word in the field value to uppercase (7.x-1.x-dev)
> - Replace some characters with some other characters in the field value (7.x-1.x-dev)
> - Link the field value to node(7.x-2.x-dev)